# Dump file creation/.NET core/Unix

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dump

I would like to programmatically create a dump file, suitable for subsequent inspection by WinDbg, from an asp.net/core application running under Unix. I need to create this file at times of my choosing, not just when there is an exception, to sort through the program’s rather complex internal state. It’s not clear to me that P/invoke and Win32 APIs are available. Suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

ProcDump is a Linux reimagining of the classic ProcDump tool from the Sysinternals suite of tools for Windows. ProcDump provides a convenient way for Linux developers to create core dumps of their application based on performance triggers.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux